# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method found among steps

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to remove the warning, `Using the ‘stage’ step without a block argument is deprecated`.  So, I'm doing is adding block for stage

```
stage 'Install Tool' {
    // code
}
```

Now, jenkins gives the error

```
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'Install Tool' found among steps [archive, bat, build, catchError, checkout, deleteDir, dir, dockerFingerprintFrom, dockerFingerprintRun, echo, emailext, emailextrecipients, envVarsForTool, error, fileExists, findFiles, getContext, git, httpRequest, input, isUnix, library, libraryResource, load, mail, milestone, node, parallel, properties, pwd, readFile, readJSON, readManifest, readMavenPom, readProperties, readTrusted, readYaml, resolveScm, retry, script, sh, slackSend, sleep, stage, stash, step, svn, timeout, timestamps, tool, touch, unarchive, unstash, unzip, validateDeclarativePipeline, waitUntil, withContext, withCredentials, withDockerContainer, withDockerRegistry, withDockerServer, withEnv, wrap, writeFile, writeJSON, writeMavenPom, ws, zip] or symbols [all, allOf, always, ant, antFromApache, antOutcome, antTarget, any, anyOf, apiToken, architecture, archiveArtifacts, artifactManager, batchFile, booleanParam, branch, buildButton, buildDiscarder, caseInsensitive, caseSensitive, choice, choiceParam, clock, cloud, command, cron, crumb, defaultView, demand, disableConcurrentBuilds, docker, dockerfile, downloadSettings, downstream, dumb, envVars, environment, expression, file, fileParam, filePath, fingerprint, frameOptions, freeStyle, freeStyleJob, git, github, githubPush, gradle, hyperlink, hyperlinkToModels, installSource, jdk, jdkInstaller, jgit, jgitapache, jnlp, jobName, junit, label, lastDuration, lastFailure, lastGrantedAuthorities, lastStable, lastSuccess, legacy, legacySCM, list, local, location, logRotator, loggedInUsersCanDoAnything, masterBuild, maven, maven3Mojos, mavenErrors, mavenMojos, mavenWarnings, modernSCM, myView, node, nodeProperties, nonStoredPasswordParam, none, not, overrideIndexTriggers, paneStatus, parameters, password, pattern, pipeline-model, pipelineTriggers, plainText, plugin, pollSCM, projectNamingStrategy, proxy, queueItemAuthenticator, quietPeriod, run, runParam, schedule, scmRetryCount, search, security, shell, skipDefaultCheckout, skipStagesAfterUnstable, slave, stackTrace, standard, status, string, stringParam, swapSpace, text, textParam, tmpSpace, toolLocation, unsecured, upstream, usernameColonPassword, usernamePassword, viewsTabBar, weather, zfs, zip] or globals [currentBuild, docker, env, params, pipeline, scm]
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:149)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:108)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObject$invokeMethod$30.call(Unknown Source)
```

Is adding block the right thing to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct Groovy syntax would be:

```java
stage('Install Tool') {
    // code
}
```